# How to protect a Worksheet in a Shared Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which will be shared among multiple users. A macro will be run to enter data from userform in the Excel sheet.

The sheet needs to be protected so users can't edit it.

I had ws.Unprotect

My macro code

```
ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

When the workbook is shared it shows the following error:

> runtime error 1004 method ' protect of object '_worksheet' failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared Workbooks/Worksheets have limitations... check here.. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. So there is no way that the shared worksheet can be protected and run the macro ?

Comment: I'm searching work around for this issue since 3 years. But failed. Till the time I didn't find any solution for this. So either I create separate data file for each user & one Master data file. Before start working I distribute data from Master to every one and At the end update master file with the user's data files. It is quite lengthy code but works for me most of the time. If only one user is using the protected file and updating using macros it work perfectly fine.

Comment: I have multiple users accessing the data, making changes at the same time.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. But you can find a way to do it if you distribute the data between users. and collect after their work is done. Seems to be silly, but it works for me.

Comment: I think it's better to use MS Access for such situation, where there shouldn't be problem with multiple users accessing same data source, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes it is better. But excel is very flexible and easy to use as compare with Access. Both has their own positive & negative points.