# AllowEditRange reprotection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm completly new at this and trouble is that I got to keep Office97 compatibility. My friends call me "Ctrl+C - Ctrl+V coder", so sorry if that's a stupid question.

I've got this timestamp event runing, but it can't put value in protected sheet. I can't turn off protection while file is shared. I found AllowEditRange VBA command, so i can put timestamp in the field, but can't protect it back. I can make workaround with hidden sheet, but it's not as tidy, as "re-protection".

```
ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Item(1).Unprotect "Password"
```

Is there any way to make this line work just for 1 modification, but every time i call it? Or only for VBA modifications, and not user interface? Documentation leaves no hope. I've spent way to much time on looking it up on forums.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611. `Documentation leaves no hope` - weird, that's [where I got it from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect#parameters).

Comment: Been knocking that door whole morning. This "UserInterfaceOnly" flag vanishes when i turn on legacy style sharing.

EDIT: Actualy flag vanishes when i close excel and reopen it.

Comment: Yes, you are [supposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946295/11683) to execute that protection line each time you open the file.

Comment: When I try that in on_open event I get runtime error first moment i enable macros. Problem lays in "share" part as I've found some post in here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866544/how-to-protect-a-worksheet-in-a-shared-workbook